# Cron expression to run job twice a day at different time?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I have one job that needs to be execute twice a day at different time .
e.g. 10:00 and 15:30.
How can i achieve this ?

I am confuse because minute is different for both the time.
For 11:00 and 15:00 its easy because for both the times, minute portion is same, but for the different minute portion is it feasible with cron ?

Thanks in Advance and apologies for silly question.

Comment: What is the reason for just one job?

Comment: That cannot be done with a single trigger... 0 0,30 10,15 * * ? will fire at 1000, 1030, 1500 and 1530, 0 0 10,15 * * ? will fire at 1000 and 1530 and 0 30 10,15 * * ? at 1030 and 1530. If you pick the first option you could add some logic to your code to skip the runs you need to skip.

Answer (score 9):

Try following which you will get closest in one expression

```
0 0 10,15/12 * * ?
```

this will run 10:00 and 15:00.

Comment: Why the `/12` ?

Comment: /12 - means it run every 12 hours which make twise a day.

Comment: It does if you just say `/12`, but your current `10,15/12` says _at minute 0 past hour 10 and every 12th hour from 15 through 23_. https://crontab.guru/#0_10,15/12_*_*_*

Comment: nope - /12 means  2 times a day not 1 time in 24 hours at different time specified 10 and 15.  you can test this one at http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: yes I know what `/12` does, my point is that 15/12 does not make any sense.

Comment: That will not run at 1000 and 1500, / is used for increments and the way this is written will result in an invalid cron expression.

Comment: with/out /12 it means the same. 
This 15/12 means, it will run every 12 hours from 15 to 23.
15 then 27(which doesn't make any sense)

 0 0 10,15 * *

Although who asked the question doesn't want this

Answer (score 8):

You can set values for each job:

```
0 10 * * * job

30 15 * * * job
```

Here is more info:

```
*    *    *    *    *  command to be executed
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    └───── day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 are Sunday, or    use names)
│    │    │    └────────── month (1 - 12)
│    │    └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
└───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

Wikipage about cron https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Thanks, for your comment . I knew this but I want this in SINGLE cron expression instead of two different expressions .

Comment: In this case I really recommend using two separate cron entries. It is easier to maintain than some stupid hack.

Answer (score 2):

Cron Expression can not use for multiple specific times such as 10:00 am and 15:30 on the same expression. But you can use the multiple expressions by  specifying one time in each expression such as 0, 10 * * * to 10:00 AM and anther expression like this 30 15 * * *  for  15:30. According to Creon expression convention you CAN NOT specify multiple specific times on the same expression.

DO NOT Try this such this expression  0,10 10,15 * * * This executes in below time.

10:00 AM
10:30 AM
15:00 PM
15:30 PM

Answer (score -1):

I have tried using 0 1,6 * * ? * expression for my request - to schedule job during 1am and 6am every day. So for your request to schedule 10:00 and 15:00 time, i believe the following cron expression should work. Please give a try and let me know
0 10,15 * * ? *

Comment: Hello @Shammu, welcome to StackOverflow. This does not answer the question. Ravi is actually trying to get a cron for 10:00 and 15:30. In the post it was even mentioned that for 11 and 15 would be easy to configure.

Comment: Got it, i have overlooked the minute. I believe it is achievable only by two different expressions as called out by lipponen. Single expression is possible if the minutes are also same. Thanks for reviewing it @JulianoCosta