# How to set two cron on the same springboot method?

Tags: spring-boot, cron, spring-scheduled

I want to set a timer at 9:00 / 16:30. But one cron can not realize it.
So i need two cron to realize it. The corn is as follows:

```
cron1: * 30 16 * * *
cron2: * * 9 * * *
```

I want to set cron by springboot @Schedule like this

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 2 * * ?")
public void sayHello(){}
```

But it seems that can not support two @Scheduled label on one method or two cron in one label.

The so low method is as follow, Any better advice？

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* 30 16 * * ?")
public void sayHello(){}

@Scheduled(cron = "* * 9 * * ?")
public void subSayHello(){sayHello();}
```

Comment: I think it's not supported, referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993556/execute-crontab-twice-daily-at-00h-and-1330, since the spring schedule is a cron-like expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is difficult because of the different min and different hour, 
if the cron run in the same hour or min, it will be easy.

Such as:

```
"*  0,30  9    * * ?"
"*  0     9,16 * * ?"
```

Or you can see this link [Cron expression to run job twice a day at different time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434029/cron-expression-to-run-job-twice-a-day-at-different-time)