# Azure Timer Function Twice in same day

Tags: azure-functions

Is it possible to pass parameters with the CRON format to an Azure C# timer function that will have it run twice in the same day at two specified times? I need to run my function at 11 AM and 3 AM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cron expression to run job twice a day at different time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434029/cron-expression-to-run-job-twice-a-day-at-different-time)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want it to run at 3am and 11am you could try the below corn expression:

```
0 0 3,11 * * *
```

Furthermore details about the corn expression you could refer to this doc:[NCRONTAB expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions).

A CRON expression except that it includes an additional sixth field at the beginning to use for time precision in seconds:

```
{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}
```

Answer (score 0):

Timer trigger can only take a single cron schedule.
So one function can't do that

so create 2 functions now for 11 am and another for 3 am 
make this 2 function call the same service