# Cron expression at 8:00 and 16:30 from monday to friday

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs

How can I write a CRON expression that will invoke Azure WebJob Monday through Friday at 8:00 AM and 4:30 PM?

Comment: Your question is no great fit for SO. Please refer to [ask]. On-topic: there are quite a few decent tools out there, like [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_8,17_*_*_1,5) which might give insight in to how to build your cron expression. Please be advised this uses a different cron expression than the ones used in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a job triggering at 8AM and 16PM Monday through Friday using

```
0 0 8,16 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
```

If you definitely need 16:30, you will need 2 CRON triggers.

```
0 0 8 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
0 0 16 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
```

You can check your CRONs [HERE](http://www.cronmaker.com/;jsessionid=node012g2o33f9896a1576d5q68cv8j1848779.node0?0).

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434029/cron-expression-to-run-job-twice-a-day-at-different-time/41876266) existing question, Single CRON is possible if the minute triggering is the same.

Comment: Hi @Pawlit, have you checked my answer? If it answers your questions, kindly mark it as the answer so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have used this and it worked for me:
0 3 * * 1-5

The above format is basically-
(min) (hr) (day in month) (month) (day in week)